# Encountered unsupported property EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm having some issues with a Cloudformation Template where when I attempt to roll it out it keeps failing on the instance creation prompting the error ' Encountered unsupported property EBS' which in turn causes a rollback. I find this quite interesting because I appear to have all of the necessary properties in there at the moment:

Also Including some links that could help speed up the research:
[Instance Setup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html), 
[Block Device Mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-mapping.html), & 
[Block Specific Properties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-template.html)

```
 Resources:  
   Web01:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
            SecurityGroups: 
                        - Ref: SecurityGoupSocoDrELB
                        - Ref: SecurityGoupSocoDrData
            KeyName: 
                    Ref: KeyPairName
            ImageId: !FindInMap
                - RegionMap
                - Ref: "AWS::Region"
                - AMI
            Monitoring: 'false'
            SubnetId:
                    Ref: SocoDrSubnet02
            PrivateIpAddress: xxxxxxxx
            InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior: 'stop'
            InstanceType: 
                        Ref: InstanceType
             #I think the error occurs here-
            BlockDeviceMappings:
                - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
                - EBS:
                    DeleteOnTermination: 'true'
                    VolumeType: gp2
                    VolumeSize: '300'
```

**For reference I'm including other appropriate sections but the problem is stemming from the Resource's Instance section:**

```
Parameters:
  KeyPairName:
    Description: The EC2 Key Pair to allow SSH access to the instance
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName

# INSTANCE
InstanceType:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
        - t2.nano
        - t2.micro
        - t2.small
        - t2.medium
        - t2.large
        - t2.xlarge
        - t2.2xlarge
    Default: t2.small
Mappings:
  RegionMap:
    us-east-2: 
        AMI: ami-014a7d64
```

Comment: It should be `Ebs` and not `EBS`.

Comment: Of course it is. Thank you, that answers my question.

Comment: Awesome. I will post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct property is `Ebs` and not `EBS`. Documentation can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-mapping.html).